# Можно ли с помощю Spring нажать кнопку на сайте?

Tags: java, spring

Допустим пытаюсь с помощью Фреймворка Spring,  на сайте "https://ru.stackoverflow.com"  нажать на кнопку-"Задать вопрос". Это можно сделать с помощью Spring и можно ли вообще?

Comment: все можно. как вы собираетесь открыть браузер, перейти на сайт... ?

Comment: Дратути @Senior Pomidor , с помощью REST запросов, только проблема инициализация (я так и не познал как это сделать )

Comment: то есть вам нужно авторизоваться на сайте, иначе доступа нет к определенной странице, так?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor   Да, но REST запросы я реализую через библиотеку  Jersy (хотя возможна проблема в библиотеке все говорят Apach лучше)

Comment: Я просто хочу понять можно ли с помощью  Фреймворка Spring реализовать такой  механизьм

Comment: может лучше использовать для этого [stackexchange api](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication)

Comment: смотри лучше в сторону Selenium.
Каждой задаче свой инстурмент,
зачем тебе спринг чтобы просто на кнопку нажать?

Comment: @polk1lo не просто кнопку нажать, но и получить подтверждение (код 200), так сказать взаимодействие по REST  протоколу.

Comment: @polk1lo а какие проблемы с REST запросом?

Comment: @batman такие что он GET запрос выдает мне всю страницу в xml и всё. Инициализироваться не получается хотя и делаю по стандартной библиотеке java (java.net(?<>=<>&<>=<>)) так что пытаюсь схватиться за последнюю ветку. Библиотека jersey тоже не помогла, в библиотеку (Apache HttpComponents) пока не лез. НО хотелось бы найти хороший много функциональный инструмент с которым получиться долго работать, по этому и стал смотреть в сторону  Фреймворка Spring.

Comment: @timob256 тебе же выше написали использовать  stackexchange api , вот прямая ссылка на АПИ добавления вопроса - https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-question

Comment: @polk1lo вы не поняли моего вопроса.